# Align contents centered on page

Tags: jquery, css

I want to center the carousel contents on the page and also have a background which is fixed and changes height/width based on browser resize.

Please let me know how do I accomplish it, from the code i have.

Answer (score 1):

For centering it delete the `left: 50%;` on the `ul` css.

For the background use this css:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('replaceme');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

and replace `replaceme` with the image you want.

**Note:** *the background css has some css3 artibutes that may not work in older internet explorers, if you dont want to use css3 consider using this site:* http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_stretch_background_image.cfm

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
text-align:center;
```

to the body and remove

```
left:50%;
```

from the ul, that will center the roundabout.

As for the background image, you can set a div to 100% width, position absolute, top and bottom 0px with an image set to 100% width to dynamically scale however for a better CSS3 approach have a look on csstricks.com, there is a very good tutorial on it there.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Paradise answer is working, but only in IE but not in FF. any idea? and your background information helped. thanks

Comment: Paradise's answer is an old CSS technique for centring elements with a defined width, it works but is not an ideal approach imo. When you say it works in IE, what version are you referring to and what versions do you need to support? (IE6 or simply IE8+?). Did you try my answer above, removing left:50% and adding text-align:center on the body? This is a pretty standard technique and should work cross browser.

Comment: Your page has been flagged as unsafe: Google has found malicious software may be installed onto your computer if you proceed. If you've visited this site in the past or you trust this site, it's possible that it has just recently been compromised by a hacker. You should not proceed, and perhaps try again tomorrow or go somewhere else.

Comment: I am not sure why it says that, but It's perfectly safe i assure you. Maybe try visiting tomorrow?

Answer (score 1):

Since none of above solutions include both vertical and horizontal centering, add this to your ul class, if this is what you are trying to achieve

```
ul {

 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: -15em 0 0 -31em;
 width: 62em;
 height: 30em;
 background-color: #0C0C0C;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;

}
```

For full resizable background I'll go with FrontEndJohn solution, just keep in mind to add min-width and min-height to body so your image don't stretches too much

Comment: Paradise, your stylesheet worked perfect. but if you check it firefox, it's not correct.

Comment: this should work on any browser is the proper way to center things when working with absolutely positioned objects, check this http://jsfiddle.net/sT7Gh/ tested on FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome, IE7-9, try adding position:absolute to your ul class, I might deleted that propertie when editing your rule I just noticed it should be there